# Keycloak: The token has invalid signature

Tags: reactjs, jwt, keycloak

I am using Keycloak as an auth provider for a React app. I have utilized k8s helm deployment for Keycloak deployment (Used this [Bitnami package for Keycloak](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/keycloak)). On the React side, I am using [@react-keycloak/web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-keycloak/web).

I am wrapping the entire app with ReactKeycloakProvider:

```
<ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={client}>
  <App />
</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

To obtain the access token, I am utilizing the useKeycloak() hook from @react-keycloak/web:

```
const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();const token = keycloak?.token;
```

The issue lies with the token signature (Checked using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)). When running Keycloak locally, the signature is valid. However, when using the deployed Keycloak, I am encountering an error - invalid signature. I am using the `RS256` algorithm for decoding. I want to use OAuth 2.0 auth code grant type.

I am using these settings in keycloak. [Keycloak settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBetp.png)

I am seeking assistance in identifying the potential cause of this issue.

I tried decoding the access token using the HS256 algorithm. I expected the token signature to be valid when using the deployed Keycloak. However, the actual result was an error indicating an invalid signature.
The local keycloak token has a valid signature.

Comment: Do you use correct secret to decode token? I mean, do you use secret of deployed Keycloak, not your local one?

Comment: BTW, It seems like it's not a very good idea to use HS256 in your situation (it's symmetric algorithm and keeping it's secret key on the front-end is unsafe)

Comment: Sorry, Its RS256. I am decoding it in JWT.io to see the details.

Comment: RS256 is Ok. Are you sure you use correct public key (from deployed Keycloak) when you decode token?

Comment: I'm not an expert in react, but I want to figure out. How do you configure the `client` that you use in this line `<ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={client}>`?

Comment: Something like `const client = Keycloak({url: '...', realm: '...', clientId: '...',});` Check whether you use correct URL

Comment: You are right about client creation. I have rechecked the URL. It is correct.